# Script execution order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I did Generate Script on a database and got over 1700 scripts. I've sorted them into folders below:

[image]

Each folder contains .sql files of that type, for example `06 UserDefinedFunction` contains many `.UserDefinedFunction.sql` files.

I'm going to make a batch script that goes to each folder and runs `sqlcmd` on every file in that folder.

Does the execution order matter here, and do I have the right order?

Comment: Shouldn't you let your source control system do / manage this for you? Why do you want to manually manage 1700 scripts? Seems you only create more work and (as already mentioned) more problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution order absolutely matters, and you shouldn't change it from what was generated. It is likely you have **dependencies** in one script on objects that need to be created first from another script. For example, if one of your **Stored Procedures** use a **View** then it will fail upon generation because it can't find the **View** it references. This is why generating scripts puts them in order by **dependency** instead of object type.

Only in the very rare case where all your scripts don't have **dependencies** on each other (or your re-ordering is coincendentally in order of **dependency** still), then you'd be ok.

Comment: The generated order was alphabetical so the file name with lower letter came first no matter if it was table or procedure or function etc.

Comment: @Jam I'm not sure how you generated your scripts (as **SSMS** usually generates only 1 script file per database, and it's **dependency** based), but regardless, if you have **dependencies** in some of your script files, on objects that don't exist yet (such as my example in my answer) then that script will fail. If you're saying you manually generated a script for each individual object in alphabetical order, then you're definitely going to run into a **dependency** problem when you try to run them. You should generate scripts at the database level instead if you need a large portion of it.

Comment: I purposefully chose to generate one script per object because when I chose single script file it and tried to run it it got errors and I couldn't open the script file in a text editor because it was 60 GB. There errors were many of `Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.` and I couldn't know how to locate the errors in a 33 million line file.

Comment: I understand it's not possible to determine the right order just by looking at the folders above.

Comment: @Jam 1,700 objects shouldn't create a 60 GB script file, so that's **very** weird in itself, and you might want to look into that. Regardless, you shouldn't have to open / modify the generated script file at all, it should be errorless as is, and can be executed without opening it. You've received that error when trying to execute the script or when you tried to open it in a text editor?

Comment: @Jam To your second comment, correct, it's not possible to determine the correct script order based on your folders above. Some scripts for **Stored Procedures** might depend on **Views** you haven't created yet, and other **Stored Procedures** might not.

Comment: @Jam, seems like you are scripting data also with script options, I would suggest you to have a single file for the "Schema Only" option, which will take care of the dependency and multiple files for the "Data only" option.

Comment: @Bijujose That's a great point, that's likely the source of his 60 GB big script files and "*unclosed quotation*" error. Scripting just the schema should result in a file a few MBs big at best lol.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a dacpac to do the same thing in a proper way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-ver15